# Allow same user to connect to Django server from Angular2 client and other Django server

Tags: python, django, angular, python-requests, django-csrf

We have this setup:

- Central Django server, CSRF and login enabled. Except for the login no action may be performed without logging in previously.
- An Angular2 client which connects for almost every call to the central server. The login on the central server is executed from here. CSRF token is available and authentication works.
- Another small server which takes files. It is also Django but not CSRF enabled. The client sends files to this server which the central server may never possess or even see. The file upload (using form-data and POST) works fine. However, after a file upload has been completed, we would like this small server to call the central server notifying it of the successful upload.

The problem is the last step. The central server refuses the call, saying we need to be logged in. Can we in any way make the central server believe that the request came from the user who logged in with the Angular2 client? How do we have to set up the CSRF token? We are sending the user's CSRF token he got in the client to the small server.

We are using the python-requests library, Python 3 and Django 1.10.
This is the code we currently have on the small server:

```
url = settings.CENTRAL_SERVER_URL + 'path/to/endpoint'

# 'request' is the original request object from the Angular2 client
token = get_token(request)

# Call to 'post' results in error code in response ('not logged in')
response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers={'X-CSRFToken': token, 'Referer': url})
```

I assume the problem is the 'headers' definition. Can it be done at all?

(CSRF enabled = uses CsrfViewMiddleware)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was on the right track. It is most important to include the session ID the client got when logging in also in the new request to the central server.
Here is the code:

```
url = settings.CENTRAL_SERVER_URL + 'path/to/endpoint'

http_x_token = request.META['HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN']
csrftoken = request.COOKIES['csrftoken']
session_id = request.COOKIES['sessionid']

response = requests.post(url, data=data, 
    headers={'X-CSRFToken': http_x_token, 'Referer': url}, 
    cookies={'csrftoken': csrftoken, 'sessionid': session_id})
```

The session ID should always be present in the request from the client.
SessionMiddleware in Django checks for this. If the session ID is present, the user can be found and everything else works as if I was making a request from the client.